# Display stringified json as tree in console params

Tags: json, ajax, firefox

Firefox developer used to show my ajax json data in outbound xhr POST as a tree. Now it shows as a string. How do I get it to display as a tree again?

Answer (score 0):

If you get this issue change this setting by typing about:config
devtools.netmonitor.responseBodyLimit. To disable the limit, set it to 0 or just increase it to a new value